# Conditional binding and execution in Clojure

Tags: clojure

There's a form that comes up often in my Clojure code and I'd like to know if there's some way to simplify it.

Here's a description of behavior "do operation X, if the result of operation matches a predicate, bind the result to a variable Y and execute some code.

Here's an implementation I'm using now:

```
(let [op-result (op ...)]
  (if-let [my-var (when (pred op-result) op-result)]
     then else))
```

Seems far too verbose for what I'm trying to accomplish. Does anyone have any suggestions (apart from writing my own macro)?

Comment: You're just "aliasing" `op-result` to `my-var` which can be omitted, so just a simple `(if (pred op-result) then else)`. Or is your example more complex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you want to use `op-result` in the "then" branch. But many predicate functions return `true` not their argument. So you can't simply write this:

```clojure
(if-let [op-result (pred (op))]
  op-result ;maybe `true`, but you want `(op)`
  false)
```

The core expression you want is:

```
(and (pred x) x)
```

You could write

```
(if-let [op-result (and (pred (op)) (op))]
  op-result
  false)
```

But if `(op)` is expensive, this is better:

```
(if-let [op-result (let [x (op)] (and (pred x) x))]
  op-result
  false)
```

Of course that's a bit tedious, so if you need that a lot, it might be worth writing a macro.

---

I suppose another approach is to make predicates "truthy":

```
(defn truthy
  "Given a predicate function, return a new function.
  When the original predicate function returns true for some value,
  the new function returns the value (instead of true). Else returns
  false."
  [pred]
  (fn [v]
    (and (pred v) v)))

((truthy even?) 2) ; 2
((truthy even?) 3) ; false

(if-let [op-result ((truthy pred) (op))]
  op-result ;use op-result
  false)
```

Again, a macro might be handy.

---

In some Lisps I'd use pattern-matching (`match` in Racket, `pcase` in Emacs Lisp). These are forms like `cond`; often they let you apply a predicate for a test, while binding the original value. I'm not sure if `core.match` can do this, or, if you want to include it solely to do this.

---

Finally, I fully expect someone to point out that something like this already exists as a one-liner in Clojure that I don't know. :)  But I figured I'd attempt an answer since no one else had, yet.

Comment: The problem with `(and (pred x) x)` is that I have to have `x` already bound somewhere, I need an extra let sentence somewhere, or I have to calculate it twice.

Comment: Exactly. The two approaches I can see are (a) use an extra `let` binding, or, (b) "enhance" the predicates to behave in a "truthy" fashion. (At some level they're equivalent, since a function is a binding of its arguments; in theory you can build `let` in terms of function application. But at this level, which do you prefer?) Either would be more convenient in a macro, but, it's usually good to explore/try what code you'd want a macro to write for you.